# Kendo Grid Select All checkbox not working for Virtualization Angular

Tags: kendo-grid, angular12, kendo-angular-ui

I am working on kendo grid virtualization with Select All feature. Since virtualization is used only visible records will be checked when "Select All" checkbox is checked. I have referred this [link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/persisting/) where all records would be checked even with pagination. I am trying to achieve the same with virtualization, but as on second scroll records won't be checked by default.

Here is the stackblitz link of what i am trying to achieve
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3qtagj?file=app/app.component.html

Please let me know where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you change Items to query because grid data is query .

You can see it on the link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3qtagj-zwjvef?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).